# php javascript autopopulated image gallery

Tags: javascript, php

I get the error message syntax error missing ; before statement at "var galleryarray=new Array();" . "\n"; here is the php code

```
function returnimages($dirname=".") {
    $pattern="\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$";
    $files = array();$curimage=0;
    if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
            if(eregi($pattern, $file)){
                echo 'galleryarray[' . $curimage .']=["' . $file . '"];' . "\n";
                $curimage++;
            }
        }
    closedir($handle);
    }
    return($files);
}
echo "var galleryarray=new Array();" . "\n";
returnimages();
```

and here is the javascript:

```
var galleryarray=new Array(); 
var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "slideshow_images/"+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500)
}
```

i just don't see my mistake any help with this problem would be appreciated

klein

Comment: var curimg=0 miss a semicolumn at the end

Answer (score 1):

Replace your below line:

```
echo "var galleryarray=new Array();" . "\n";
```

with the following line:

```
echo "<script>var galleryarray=new Array();</script>";
```

You are adding a JS code without script tag so you need to add this tag.

**EDITED:**

```
echo 'galleryarray[' . $curimage .']=["' . $file . '"];' . "\n";
```

You also have error in the above line replace it with the below line:

```
echo '<script>galleryarray["' . $curimage .'"]=["' . $file . '"];</script>';
```

Comment: thanks for the help code lover but now I get the error msg syntax error; expected statement got <

Comment: @kleinmorgan replace double quota " with single quota ' and then try. hope this will work

Comment: I have tried replacing the double quotes with singles but now I get

Comment: syntax error missing; before statement echo 'galleryarray[' . $curimage .']=["' . $file . '"];' . "\n";

Comment: thanks marco mura but adding the semicolumn does not bring the rest of the images.  the gallery is still getting stuck on the first image

Comment: @kleinmorgan you have error in other line that time. check the updated answer.

Comment: hi thanks code lover but now I get the error msy syntax error missing ; before statement echo '<script>galleryarray["' . $curimage .'"]=["' . $file . '"];</script>';

Comment: im now getting the error message syntax error: expected expression got > at line echo '<script>var galleryarray=new Array();</script>';